# Python subprocess echo not passing quoted text to end of file

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to append this line to the end of a file

```
    zone_text = 'zone \"domain.com\" { type master; file \"/etc/bind/zones/domain.com\";};'
    add_zone_file = subprocess.Popen(
        ['ssh', NAMESERVERS[0], '/bin/echo', '"{}"'.format(zone_text), '>>', '/etc/bind/named.conf.local'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

But when I inspect the file it outputs this into it

```
zone domain.com { type master; file /etc/bind/zones/domain.com;};
```

And I need it to output this

```
zone "domain.com" { type master; file "/etc/bind/zones/domain.com";};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using [shlex.quote()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote). It should help. There's also an option to use `shell=True` to `Popen()`, but this one has some negative security aspects.